# Returned Facebook feed not containing user name

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I used Facebook API c# to returning all feeds in specific page but the returned data not containing any information about user who added this feed all what I need return with every feed the name of user who add this post and the user id if it is possible.

This code was working before and "from" element in json was returning user name and id but now "from" element returns null but other data like feed message and feed id are returned

```
dynamic result = client2.Get("/" + fbPageID + "/feed/");
                    JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());
                    if (o2["data"] != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in o2["data"])
                        {

                            string post_id = item["id"] != null ? item["id"].ToString() : null;
                            dynamic result2 = client2.Get("/" + post_id + "/user/");
                            string message = item["message"] != null ? item["message"].ToString() : null;
                            string Name = (item["from"] != null) ? (item["from"]["name"] != null ? item["from"]["name"].ToString() : null) : null;
                            string FacebookUserID = (item["from"] != null) ? (item["from"]["id"] != null ? item["from"]["id"].ToString() : null) : null;
                            string time = item["created_time"] != null ? item["created_time"].ToString() : null;
                        }
                     }
```

Comment: are you using a page token? afaik there are many threads on stackoverflow about this already.

Comment: @luschn yes i used access token and data is returned except user who add the post